# loading json content to html table with php

Tags: php, html, json

i've the same search like mine alot here, but mine is a bit more complexe and didn't know how to make it work.

so i have this json content: (this is one of 84 objects inside a json table)

```js
{
        "number": "6",
        "name": "Le Nickel : ses oxydes, ses sels et les opérations de grillage de mattes de nickel",
        "cause":
            {
                "A":"<p><strong><u>Liste indicative des principaux travaux</u></strong></p><p>Nickelage électrolytique des métaux</p>",
                "B": "<p><strong><u>Liste limitative des travaux</u></strong></p><p>Nickelage électrolytique des métaux</p><p>Opérations de soudage sur des métaux contenant du Nickel.</p>",
                "C": "<p><strong><u>Liste limitative des travaux</u></strong></p><p>Opérations de grillage de mattes de nickel. Opérations de soudage sur des métaux contenant du nickel.</p>"
            },
        "content": {
            "A": [
                {
                    "des": "Dermites eczématiformes récidivantes en cas de nouvelles expositions ou confirmées par test épicutané.",
                    "period": "7 jours"
                }
            ],
            "B": [
                {
                    "des": "Rhinite, asthme ou dyspnée asthmatiforme confirmés par test ou par épreuves fonctionnelles, récidivant après nouvelle exposition au risque.",
                    "period": "7 jours"
                }
            ],
            "C": [
                {
                    "des": "Cancer primitif de l’ethmoïde et des sinus de la face.Cancer bronchique primitif.",
                    "period": "40 ans"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

and i want to add them to this table based on search result

```html
<tr>
            <th>Tableau</th>
            <th>Désignation des maladies</th>
            <th>Délai de prise en charge</th>
            <th>Liste indicative des principaux travaux susceptibles de provoquer ces maladies</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
```

when i search through the cause array everything works fine but when i loop through the content arrays thats when every thing just goes to hell.

this is my php code for the search:

```html
$index = 0;
            $output ="";
            $first = "";
            $last = "";
                foreach($table["content"]["A"] as $content){
                    if(strpos($content["des"],$search)){
                        if($index == 0){
                            $first.= "<tr>";
                            $first.= "<td>".$table["number"]."</td>";
                            $first.= "<td>".$content["des"]."</td>";
                            $first.= "<td>".$content["period"]."</td>";
                            $$last.= '<td><a href="add.php"><button type="button">Ajoutez au suivi</button></a></td>';
                            $$last.= "</tr>";
                        }else{
                            $output.= "<tr>";
                            $output.= "<td>".$table["number"]."</td>";
                            $output.= "<td>".$content["des"]."</td>";
                            $output.= "<td>".$content["period"]."</td>";
                            $output.= '<td><a href="add.php"><button type="button">Ajoutez au suivi</button></a></td>';
                            $output.= "</tr>";
                        }
                        $index++;
                    }
                }
            echo $first;
            echo "<td rowspan=\"".$index."\">".$table["cause"]["A"]."</td>";
            echo $last;
            echo $output;
            $index =0;
```

and this is what happens when i run it :

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfH6r.png)

i was hoping i find an answer here, thnks all for your time and for the help.

Comment: You have loop your object at the beginning then inside the loop you have to loop through each content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prepare table in php and display it with ajax/get. It will be easier to find a problem.

Comment: i guess i'm only left with that, but i'm not sure if i just post the result with ajax or loop through the json and create the table directly with js

Comment: no everything works fine the problem is with the logic of the code

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
foreach($table as $content){
    foreach ($content as $objContent) {
        if(strpos($objContent["des"],$search)){
        if($index == 0){
            $first.= "<tr>";
            $first.= "<td>".$table["number"]."</td>";
            $first.= "<td>".$objContent["des"]."</td>";
            $first.= "<td>".$objContent["period"]."</td>";
            $$last.= '<td><a href="add.php"><button type="button">Ajoutez au suivi</button></a></td>';
            $$last.= "</tr>";
        }else{
            $output.= "<tr>";
            $output.= "<td>".$table["number"]."</td>";
            $output.= "<td>".$objContent["des"]."</td>";
            $output.= "<td>".$objContent["period"]."</td>";
            $output.= '<td><a href="add.php"><button type="button">Ajoutez au suivi</button></a></td>';
            $output.= "</tr>";
        }
        $index++;
    }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is not a table.
Your "cause" is an object and not  array. 
Now try to do something like this before processing:

```
$arr = json_encode($jsonstr);
```

Comment: yeah that's already done, i only copied the part where the problem exists, in other situations the code works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

try correct your typo

```
$$last.=
```

to be

```
$last.=
```